# Intuition for Blow-up.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

If I blow up a complex manifold along a submanifold, can you give me a picture to have in mind for the blown-up manifold? Can you also tell me why this is the right picture?

Comment: A great plan would be to read the corresponding part in Eisenbud and Harris' *The Geometry of Schemes*. Blowing up a subsomething replaces each point by the set of (first order) ways in which you can approach it.

Comment: "blow up" should be thought of in the sense of "blowing up a balloon" (inflation), not in the sense of "blowing up a building" (explosion).  The "blown-up" submanifold is *inflated* to a larger object while everything else in the manifold remains "the same".

Comment: Here is a tip for working with 'pictures' of complex things.  Draw a line and say that it corresponds to 1 complex dimension. This is a slight lie of course, but it can be useful for simple pictures of things like bundles.

In general, you can draw a picture on paper and say that points correspond to things in dimension n, lines to dimension n+1 and areas to n+2.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The following is more or less the description you can find in Griffiths and Harris's Principles of Algebraic Geometry on page 182.

For the case of a point in a complex manifold, the idea is to take a local neighborhood homeomorphic to a disc $\Delta$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ centered at 0, and take the projection $\pi: \tilde{\Delta} \longrightarrow \Delta$ where $\tilde{\Delta} = \{(z,l) | z_il_j = z_j l_i \,\forall i,j \}\subset \mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ where $z \in \Delta$ and $l\in \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.  (If you have trouble seeing this as a manifold, perhaps recall that there is an embedding of $\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^m$ into $\mathbb{P}^{(n+1)(m+1)-1}$ and work out the defining equations in that space).

Away from $z = 0$ the projection $(z,l) \mapsto z$ is going to be one-to-one. In fact it is a homeomorphism.

However at $z=0$ we see that $\pi^{-1}(0) = \{ (0,l)\} \ \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$  since of course $0=0$.  Now the trick is to understand how lines through $z=0$ in $\Delta$ lift to $\tilde{\Delta}$ at $z=0$.  To do this, take the limit of the preimage of a point travelling along a line in $\Delta$ towards $0$.  You will see that it goes to $(0,l)$ where $l$ is the equivalence class of the line.

Explicitly, the line has equation $t(a_1,...,a_n)$ for $a_i\in \mathbb{C}$ not all zero and $t\in \mathbb{C}$.  If $t\neq 0$ then $\pi^{-1}(t(a_1,...,a_n)) = (t(a_1,...,a_n),[a_1:...:a_n])$. The limit as $t\rightarrow 0$ is clearly (0,[a_1:...:a_n]) in $\tilde\Delta$ and 0 in $\Delta$.

If we have a curve $C$ through $0$ in the manifold, we define the total transform of $C$ to be the homeomorphic preimage of $\pi^{-1}(C-\{0\})$ plus the points in the fibre over $0$ that correspond to the different angles at which $C$ approaches $0$.  In the zariski topology this is the closure of $\pi^{-1}(C-\{0\})$ (since these points are the limits of points in the preimage, as i described above).

To make the blow up of the manifold, one attaches $\tilde\Delta$ to $\Delta$ away from $z=0$ by the homeomorphism. Away from $0$, the other charts remain the same.

Here is some pictures from an undergrad paper, I think this helps get an intuition for how blowing up separates the slopes at 0. Here we have a node $y^2  -x^2(1+x) = 0$ and a cusp $x^2 − y^3 = 0$ in $\mathbb{C^2}$ (be careful since this is only the real picture).  In the first case, the blow up separates the curve going through $0$ by taking the preimage of $0$ to two points corresponding to the slopes of the curve through $0$. In the second case, the curve approaches 0 from one direction.

Note that the resulting total transforms are not singular.

[image: http://math.berkeley.edu/~aboocher/emma.pdf]

[image]

Here is another picture of the same thing with a local picture of the blow up of the disc, which you can find in [this great paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2003-40-03/S0273-0979-03-00982-0/S0273-0979-03-00982-0.pdf).

[image]

For the case of a higher dimensional submanifold, the intuition remains the same. As you can see from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up#Blowing_up_submanifolds_in_complex_manifolds), it is defined locally by equations that are the same as the blow up of a dimension 0 submanifold. You are taking a projection $\tilde M \longrightarrow M$ that is a homeomorphism everywhere except at the submanifold, and when you lift a curve that intersects the submanifold, we define the points in the preimage of the submanifold to be the ones corresponding to the slope at which the curve intersects it.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG4pU.png) http://math.berkeley.edu/~aboocher/emma.pdf (picture)

Comment: Someone correct me if I am wrong with the last paragraph. My knowledge for blowups of higher dimensional submanifolds is not as good.

Comment: The singularity in the picture of $V$ is a node and not a cusp. So you probably should take an equation like $y^2=x^2(x+1)$.

Comment: Of course, I attached the wrong picture... Might as well put both up then.

Comment: these pictures are fantastic

Comment: This is an exceptionally good answer.

Answer (score 7):

Not a picture and not a complex manifold, but I hope this helps. Take the curve $y^2 = x^2 (1 + x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It has a singularity (self-intersection) at the origin. The blow up embeds the curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and detaches the curve at the singularity: think about it as picking up one branch and lifting it above the other so that they don't intersect anymore. We are "blowing up" the curve at the singularity.

Comment: A picture can be found in chapter I.§4 from Hartshorne's _Algebraic Geometry_.